# Azure disable push notifications android

Tags: android, azure, notifications, push

I am switching my android application's push notification system from Urban Airship to Azure. Receiving notifications is working fine, but disabling the notifications is not working. I have a button in my settings menu which can toggle whether or not the user receives push notifications. Currently the method the button calls looks like this:

```
public static void setPushEnabled( Context context, boolean isEnabled) {
    if( isEnabled ) {
        NotificationsManager.handleNotifications(context, SENDER_ID, MyPushHandler.class);
    } else {
        NotificationsManager.stopHandlingNotifications(context);
    }
}
```

The app still receives push notifications after `stopHandlingNotifications` is called. Then if a user toggles push notifications back on, `handleNotifications` is called again, and the user receives 2 notifications for every one sent from the server. Here's the documentation for the NotificationsManager: http://dl.windowsazure.com/androiddocs/com/microsoft/windowsazure/notifications/NotificationsManager.html

Am I missing something here? Does anyone know any other ways to disable Azure push notifications?

Answer (score 1):

What I was missing was the `onUnregistered` handler in the `MyPushHandler` class, this code fixed it:

```
@Override
public void onUnregistered(Context context, final String gcmRegistrationId) {
    super.onUnregistered(context, gcmRegistrationId);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                mClient.getPush().unregisterAll(gcmRegistrationId);
                return null;
            }
            catch(Exception e) {

            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```